# How to decode large image in android in such a way that decode process should reduce image size?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, drawable, decode

How to decode large image in android in such a way that decode process should reduce image size?

The code used:

```
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("index.png"));
```

Comment: Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("index.png"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, it may help

Try decoding image with BitmapFactory.Options

Check below link for more details

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html

Thanks.